# Enviar dados selecionado em uma lista Json Externa para email (Consulta Tabela Fipe)

Tags: jquery, banco-de-dados, json, email, html-select

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var urlBase = "http://fipeapi.appspot.com/api/1/carros/";
  $.getJSON(urlBase + "marcas.json", function(data) {
    var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UMA MARCA</option>"];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      items += ("<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.name + "</option>");
    });
    $("#marcas").html(items);
  });
  $("#marcas").change(function() {
    $.getJSON(urlBase + "veiculos/" + jQuery(this).val() + ".json", function(data) {
      var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA UM VEICULO</option>"];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items += ("<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.name + "</option>");
      });
      $("#veiculos").html(items);
    });
  });
  $("#veiculos").change(function() {
    $.getJSON(urlBase + "veiculo/" + jQuery("#marcas").val() + "/" + jQuery(this).val() + ".json", function(data) {
      var items = ["<option value=\"\">ESCOLHA O ANO</option>"];
      $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items += ("<option value='" + val.id + "'>" + val.name + "</option>");
      });
      $("#ano").html(items);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <select id="marcas">
        </select>
  <select id="veiculos">
        </select>
  <select id="ano">
        </select>
</body>
```

Fiz o código para carregar o JSON usando a base desse site http://fipeapi.appspot.com/
Mas gostaria de enviar esses dados que carrega do Json por email.
A consulta funciona bem, pois também conseguiria retomar para apresentar na tela o dado concatenado completo, mas não estou sabendo fazer com que os dados selecionados na lista seja armazenado em meu banco de dados e também enviado por email.

Comment: Oi Eduardo! Não podes enviar emails diretamente do browser. Ou envias pelo servidor ou então via um site que tenha esse serviço (via ajax).

Comment: Oi @Sergio, mas não é diretamente do browser não, é sim via um servidor, mas preciso criar uma aplicação em php que envia. 
No caso aprimorei mais o código e adicionei essas linhas abaixo que converte o  `.val()` em `.text() `
`$("#nome_marca").html("<input name='" + "nome_marca" + "' value='" + $("#marcas option:selected").text() + "'/>");`
no arquivo php envioForm.php add `$MARCA = $_REQUEST['nome_marca']` isso está chamando do input que foi criado que recebe o valor `#marcas option:selected`.